# PHP mySQL preg_replace string & store result

Tags: php, mysql, database, preg-replace

So after finally bringing together code that will strip the button id from paypal form code, I'm now faced with the difficulty of getting that information stored in a database.

The PayPal code would of course look like this:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="A58F6B5HVXEBU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

With the following code, the value A58F6B5HVXEBU is removed from all of the above:

```
<?php
$string = '';
$res = preg_replace('~(.+)(name="hosted_button_id"\s+value=")([^"]+)(["].+)~s', '$3', $string);
?>
```

I know the above code needs to go into the action.php file that handles the form information and adds it to the database but I'm not sure how to arrange it. I can't seem to get it to work any way I try. I believe the name on the form would have to be different from the database row so what's in the textarea can be processed through the preg_replace code then sent to the database but I'm stuck on this one which stinks because I'm sure it's simple lol

The setup for the form and processing file look like this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" name="addclass">
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Paypal Code: </strong></td> <td><textarea name="paypal" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

action.php to add to the database:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("root","username","pass","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO tester (paypal)
VALUES
('$_POST[paypal]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "<center><h1>1 Class Added</h1>";
echo "<br /><br /><a href=view.php><font size=18>Back To List</font></a>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have been racking my brain trying different ways of implementing the preg_replace code into the action.php file to save the 13-character value string only into the database and each way I do it, the form processes and says the record has been added but only creates a blank record and doesn't store anything into the database.

Comment: Look at your SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed quotations on the key name of your post variable in the query. also you are not sanitizing any data, and you are not using prepared statements, so your script, despite using mysqli is still insecure. use `mysqli_stmt_prepare()` for any queries that contain $variables or other input. use `mysqli_query()` for queries that don't require any user submitted data or script variables.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tester (paypal)
VALUES
('".$_POST['paypal']."')";
```